# Unresolved import of Shoelace in a Stencil components project

Tags: web-component, stenciljs, shoelace

`[ WARN  ]  Bundling Warning UNRESOLVED_IMPORT            '@shoelace-style/shoelace' is imported by src/global/index.ts, but            could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency`

I got this error upon building my stencil component package. I believe I have followed the installation steps as a bundle based on Shoelace's docs, also have the Shoelace as a dependency but I still get this.

Answer (score 0):

That message is usually seen when the package has not been installed. You may need to run `npm i @shoelace-style/shoelace`.